# Make future prediction on current cpu usage data with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, machine-learning, logstash, prediction

I have written a conf file to collect log file data about cpu usage. Is there anyway to do prediction of my cpu usage in the future 30 days with my current cpu usage data in the logstash conf file?

My logs are like this.

```
"Datetime","Hostname","Location","Usage","YYMMDD","HHMM","CPU(%)",
"20150101-00:00:00","cdceap3c","DC6","EAP-Production(Production/Shared)","150101","0000","4.0",
"20150101-00:15:00","cdceap3c","DC6","EAP-Production(Production/Shared)","150101","0015","4.0",
"20150101-00:30:00","cdceap3c","DC6","EAP-Production(Production/Shared)","150101","0030","5.0",
"20150101-00:45:00","cdceap3c","DC6","EAP-Production(Production/Shared)","150101","0045","4.0",
```

Comment: That would be a machine learning job, which Logstash isn't suited for. There are plenty of resources online about this subject.

Comment: So I can only use EKL for current and historic data, right?

Comment: You can store anything into Elastic, be it past and current data but also future predictions that could be created by some other machine learning process.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you mean I can use some other machine learning process to read the CPU data and make prediction, then feed the result to elasticsearch?
Actually I only have a text file which store up the CPU Usage data. I have edited my question as for reference.

Comment: Yes, ES will store any kind of data (past, present, future). You can store past data in ES, then run some machine learning algorithm on it, make predictions and store the predictions back into ES if you so desire. But aside from storing your data and searching it, ES won't be involved in the actual prediction process.

Comment: Is there any suggestion like what tools or methods can be used to do the work once I have logstash read the data and shipped to elasticsearch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114314/discussion-between-kennedy-kan-and-val).